# How to personalise the Numbers of columns / facet layout?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a facetted plot like this:

```
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
   geom_point() +
   facet_grid(. ~ carb)
```

The layout is currently like this : 1 2 3 4 6 8

Is it possible to set the layout of the facets, i.e. to set number of columns (or rows) like?

```
   1   4   8

   2   6   

   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `ggh4x::facet_manual` which via the `design` argument allows specify the layout of the facet panels:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

design <- "
ADF
BE#
C##
"

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_manual(~ carb, design = design)
```

[image]

Instead of a character vector you could also set the order of the layout via a `matrix` where an `NA` creates a blank panel:

```
design <- matrix(c(1:3, 4:5, NA, 6, NA, NA), 3, 3)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_manual(~ carb, design = design)
```

**EDIT** Not a perfect but a quick option to some kind of column titles would be to use `patchwork`:

```r
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_manual(~ carb, design = design)

p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c("gender","sex","age"))) +
  facet_wrap(~x, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, "pt")))

library(patchwork)

p2 + p1 +
  plot_layout(heights = c(1, 100))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, can we remove the white spaces between the panels?

Comment: the white space appears if there is #

Comment: Yep. The # adds a blank panel.

Comment: any way to remove white space?

Comment: Could your clarify what do you mean by remove the white space? The white space is the `plot.background` color.

Comment: between the panels 1, 2 and 3 for instance

Comment: Aw. Sorry. I overread your first comment. You could reduce the white space in the vertical direction using `theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt")`. But not sure whether the is an option to remove it completely as some of the white space results from the axes.

Comment: yes it is from the axes of the panels in the next column

Comment: just in case you know it, can i add three titles for the three columns? c("gender","sex","age")

Comment: Hm. I would try with `patchwork`. See my edit.